# Can Azure IOT Edge device connect to the multiple Azure IOT Hubs?

Tags: azure, azure-iot-edge

Can we connect Azure IoT Edge Gateway part of multiple Azure IoT Hubs? or Any recommendations to achieve the following multiple hierarchical hubs in the Azure IoT solution?

For example device1, device2 connected to Edge Gateway.

Edge Gateway, device1, device2 -> Root Azure IoT Hub owner

Edge Gateway, Device 1 - IoT Hub 1

Edge Gateway, Device 2 - IoT Hub 2

so that relevant devices message can be forwarded to Hub1, Hub2.

Answer (score 0):

No, as of today one Edge device can only connect to one IoT Hub. To achieve your use case, I would probably use [routing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-devguide-messages-d2c) in the IoT Hub to forward messages to subsequent Event Hubs, for example with routing based on the device id or some other property that you choose.

Comment: Commenting in 2022, I came across similar situation now. I need my IoT edge gateway to talk to DEV as well as PROD IoT Hub, is there any new feature added in Azure to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

with ASA Azure Stream Analytics. in the input of the ASA configure the iothub that receives the data from the iotedge, in the outputs configure the iothubs that need to replicate the data, in the output use for iothub the "Event Hub" and put the "Event Hub compatible endpoint" of iothub.

iotedge -> iothub -> ASA -> multiples iothubs